# Pause ItemAdded event till all the attachments are added to it

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a list item with multiple attachments added to it. As soon as it is added my `ItemAdded` event is fired.

But if I try to access `properties.ListItem.Attachments` property, it sometimes gives me 0 or a number less than the original attached attachments.

If I sleep my thread for few seconds, I get the rest of my attachments in the `properties.ListItem.Attachments` property. So it looks like `ItemAdded` event is being called before all the attachments are added to the list item.

Is there a way for me to pause the `ItemAdded` event till all my attachments are added to the list item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `ItemAttachmentAdded` along with `ItemAdded`.

Since `ItemAdded` is called before `ItemAttachmentAdded`, I put a lock on a static object in `ItemAdded` and release it after the execution of `ItemAdded` event is completed.

In ItemAttachmentAdded I check for lock on that object and continue only after I get a lock which guarantees that my `ItemAttachmentAdded` item is fired after my `ItemAdded` event is completed.

```
Lock(object){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ItemAttachedAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemattachmentadded(v=office.15).aspx) event.

Comment: I am trying to copy all the attachments to a database **after** I have saved the original item in the database. So I need to do it in `ItemAdded`. Anyways I ended up using `ItemAttachmentAdded` along with `ItemAdded`